# shutdown a specific computer in a network by using C#

Tags: c#, shutdown

I have a specific PC in my local network which i want to shut it down by using C#.
I have tried some commands and solution were presented here. But none of them worked. These are the commands i have tested:

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "-s -m \\192.26.85.188");

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", @"/s /m \\192.26.85.188 /t 5 /c 'Shutdown in 5 seconds'");

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "shutdown.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\192.26.85.188 /t:10 'The computer is shutting down' /y /c";
proc.Start();

Process.Start("shutdown", string.Format(@"/s /t 0 /m \\{0}", "192.26.85.188"));

var shutdown = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", @"-m \\192.26.85.188 -s -f -t 0");
shutdown.CreateNoWindow = true;
shutdown.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(shutdown);
```

That computer ip address is 192.26.85.188.

Is there any solution for doing this? Am i doing something wrong?

One note which could be important: That PC needs Username and Password to login. Should i provide any access by this US & pass in my code?